# "Other ideas **is** for instance..." or "Other ideas **are** for instance..."

Tags: word-usage, verbs, singular-vs-plural

How should I use the verb in a case where I am refering to the plural but am finishing the sentence in singular?

> Other ideas **is** for instance to take the bike.
>
> Other ideas **are** for instance to take the bike.

Which is correct?

I can of course rephrase the sentence to something like:

> *Another idea* **is** for instance to take the bike.

But the first-mentioned examples do tell the reader that more than just one other idea do exist, and that we just only tell one example among them. The latter example does not directly contain a clue for the reader as to the fact that there are more than just this one idea.

Is one of the first-mentioned versions possible?

Comment: ***ideas*** is plural, so you must use the plural verb form.

Comment: Other ideas is plural, but here there is only one other idea: to take a/the bike.

Comment: You cannot combine *ideas* (plural) with only a single idea in that construction. You could, however, say *other ideas **include taking** the bike.* Or you could say ***another idea*** *is to take the bike.*

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence, as written, doesn't really make sense either way because you are starting the sentence talking about multiple things but finishing it talking about just one.

I would reword it.  You could use your idea or break it into two sentences.

> There are other ideas.  For instance, to take the bike.